# What can be the value of the integral $\int_{3a}^{5a}f(x)\mathrm {d}x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm working on the following problem, which is taken from a question bank for the university exam:

[image]

The graph of the function $f(x)$ defined in a certain interval is given. Each side of the quadrilateral in the figure is equal to $a$.

Suppose that the product of the integers satisfying the inequality $(f\circ f)(x)\times f'(x)<0$ is less than the largest element in the image set of the function $f(x)$. Then, what can be the value of the following integral?

$$\int_{3a}^{5a}f(x)\mathrm {d}x$$

$$\text {A)}\,4 \qquad \text{B)}\,5 \qquad \text{C)}\,6 \qquad \text{D)}\,7\qquad \text{E)}\,8$$

---

Here's my try.
I found $f(x)≤4a$ and $x_1\times x_2\times\cdots ≤4a$. Here $x_1,x_1\cdots $ are the integer solutions of $f(f(x))\times f'(x)<0$.

I also found $f'(3a)=0$

I know that in the graph, $f'(x)>0$ where the graph rises and $f'(x)<0$ where the graph of the function descends.  Unfortunately, I can't do anything with this information.

I need a good understanding of the question and an explanatory solution.

Comment: Where is this problem from? Can you state the problem in a clear and concise manner?

Comment: @IloveMath Question bank for university exam. Each side of the quadrilateral in the figure is $a$.  This is the exact form of the question.  There is no missing information.

Comment: Without further information about $a$, all answers are possible by simply choosing the right value of $a$. Is there some restriction on $a$?

Comment: @bjorn93 Unfortunately no, there is no other information. How do you find any information about $f(f(x))$ ?

Comment: @I'mastudent why is that relevant? Is it part of the problem statement?

Comment: If you estimate, you will see that $\int_{3a}^{5a} f$ is around 5a^2 units. Now, I don't see how $f(f(x)) \cdot f'(x) < 0$ will help to estimate a numerical answer non-including a in your answer. That is why I said at the beginning to state the problem correctly. Can you give us a link to the file containing this problem?

Comment: @bjborn93 No, I am just trying to understand $f(f(x))×f'(x)<0$..

Comment: @ILoveMath Unfortunately, the original question is not in English..

Comment: You should contact the creator of this problem and ask if the problem statement is actually correct. As others have already pointed out, the integral is $4.5a^2$, so you cannot determine the value of the integral without further restriction. I doubt the quality of the question bank.

Comment: @IH How did you find $4.5 a^2$ ? How can I evaluate this integral? How can I solve $f(f(x))×f'(x)<0$?

Comment: if the side length of the boxes is a, then the area of each box is $a^2$ and our answer will be in terms of $a^2$  (This assumes that the axes are orthogonal.)  Then we just need to count the boxes under the function between the end of the 3rd box and the end of the 5th box.  The function appears to be straight-line pieces.  This means that the boxes cut by the lines have an average area of 1/2.  And the total area is $4\ 1/2\ a^2$

Comment: @DougM Thank you for your comment. But, what are the integer solutions of $f(f(x))\times f'(x)<0$?

Comment: @I'm a student Forget about the inequality. That's irrelevant. I wonder why you continue to stick to it. You can evaluate the integral by purely elementary geometry.

Comment: @IH So, is this irrelevant? "Since the product of the integers satisfying the inequality $(f∘f)(x)×f′(x)<0$ is less than the largest element in the image set of the function $f(x)$..."

Comment: @I'm a student You mentioned that is not part of the problem statement in your reply to bjborn93. Then, why do you care about it?

Comment: you have been lost in translation, perhaps, or, perhaps, the problem is of poor quality, who knows... we don't want to get lost on these waters...

Comment: @IH These are the sentences written in the question.  Of course it's part of the problem.  I mean, the question doesn't say to solve this inequality.

Comment: @ILoveMath The solution is, $f(f(x))\times f'(x)<0\implies a\times 4a<4a$ , because $f(f(x))>0$

Comment: What was the statement in its original language?

Comment: By the way, $f^\prime (3a)$ is not $0$. $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=3a$. Recall the definition of differential.

Answer (score 1):

The integral is equal to $4.5a^2$.

The value of $f(x)$ is positive on the given domain. So the value of $(f\circ f)(x)$ is positive too. Then the given inequality assumption is equivalent to $f^\prime(x)<0$. From the graph, it is equivalent to $1/2\, a<x<3/2\, a$ or $3a\, <x<9/2\, a$.

You can determine the value of the integral by checking the five options one by one.

For your illustration, I will show my work on option (A).

From $4.5a^2 = 4$, you get $a=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}$. Substituting this value to the solution to the inequality, you get $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}<x<\sqrt{2}$ or $2\sqrt{2}<x<3\sqrt{2}$. So, the integer solutions to the inequality is $x=1, 3, 4$. However, the product $=12 > 4a = \frac{8\sqrt{2}}{3}$. So you can exclude the option (A).

Comment: So, is the question correct?

Comment: Because you say, "You should contact the creator of this problem and ask if the problem statement is actually correct. As others have already pointed out, the integral is 4.5a2, so you cannot determine the value of the integral without further restriction. I doubt the quality of the question bank"

Comment: I gave you an answer. First, show your work and ask again if it's still necessary.

Comment: I need to understand the question: Is this question correct or not?

Comment: You should be able to figure it out by yourself after reading my answer.

Comment: Thank you, But I still don't understand,. Because, you said that, forget about the inequality. That's irrelevant

Comment: The inequalities are now relevant. Use $4.5a^2$ and test out each of the five options as IH said. And see which ones yield the integers that satisfy the inequality.

Comment: I said that because you said the inequality is not part of the problem statement in your reply to bjorn93. It seems like many people were confused about whether it is a part of the statement or not. Please ask precisely.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Everything is part of the question, down to the answer choices.  If you notice, I drew a long line after the question was over.  Otherwise, you could ask me where $f(f(x))$ comes from.

Comment: I hope you realize that I edited your original post to make assumptions clear. Take a look at the difference between your original post and the edited one so that you can ask better next time.